# Python. How to pass parameters into function incrementally

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to pass parameters into function incrementally(?), like:

```py
def func(a, b="string0", c=False):
    print(f"a={str(a)}, b={str(b)}, c={str(c)}")

a=1
b="string"
c=True

params = [[a], [a, b], [a, b, c]]

for par in params:
    func(par)
```

current output:

```
a=[1], b=string0, c=False
a=[1, 'string'], b=string0, c=False
a=[1, 'string', True], b=string0, c=False
```

is not, that I wanted. It should trigger each actual parameter of the function according to passed number of arguments. Should behave, like:

```
func(a)
func(a, b)
func(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list unpacking as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-do-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-mean-in-a-function-call):

```
for par in params:
    func(*par)
```

This will unpack the list into consecutive arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to python, so came for this problem directly, rather from syntax and language specification first